# Php Script Solution

Tags: php, string

I have a little problem with my script. When I try to run it I receive "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING" as long as I have ' sign in my code. When I change all ' into " then I have the same error. So I have to change all " into '.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
      PutEnv(TNS_ADMIN='C:\Programy\OracleDeveloper10g\NETWORK\ADMIN\');
      $conn = oci_connect("user", "pass", "dbstring");
      if (!$conn)
      {
        $e = oci_error();
        print $e;
        exit;
      }
      else
      {
        $stmt = OCIParse($conn, "SELECT password FROM USERS WHERE username=szymon");
        OCIExecute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
      while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
      foreach ($row as $item) {
       $password = $item;
      }
        if ($password != $_POST[password]){
          $stmt = OCIParse($conn, "EXECUTE drop_tables");
          $message = "Tabele zostały usunięte";
        }
        else {
          $message = "Podane hasło jest niepoprawne";
        }
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: as far as i can see, the code you posted is bug-free ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the backslashes in the TNS_ADMIN path. The last backslash escapes the closing '.

Try doubling all backslashes:

```
C:\\Programy\\OracleDeveloper10g\\NETWORK\\ADMIN\\
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
putenv("TNS_ADMIN='C:\Programy\OracleDeveloper10g\NETWORK\ADMIN\'");
```

If you look at the docs for [putenv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) it shows everything in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you escape your `\`

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
PutEnv(TNS_ADMIN='C:\Programy\OracleDeveloper10g\NETWORK\ADMIN\');
```

The slashes cause the ending quote to be escaped.  Try it like this:

```
PutEnv(TNS_ADMIN='C:\\Programy\\OracleDeveloper10g\\NETWORK\\ADMIN\\');
```